# Is burnt looking wiring still serviceable?

Tags: bathroom, gfci

I was trying to replace a GFCI in a bathroom and the cable and wires are pretty black. The GFCI is also pretty burnt.

Do I need to replace the wiring and the GFCI or can I reuse the wire?

Comment: Sounds bad but we'd really need to see a picture to rate the level of damage to wires.   Posting a picture is much easier if: First, if you haven't already, register your account by tying it to an email/password, or Google, or Facebook.  Then, take a photo on your device of choice (login from there using the above credentials).

Comment: Your best next step is to determine WHY this is happening.  After that you will want to replace the wire that is burned since the insulation is now compromised.

Comment: Two words you *never* want to hear: burnt wire.  Bad, bad, bad...  Can we get a picture?

Comment: As others have said a photo is needed, it is possible the black is from arcing but we can not tell from just a description. Soot that wipes off is normally not a problem but melted wire that needs to be trimmed back and don’t use the push in connectors or back stabs use the screw terminals. Back stabs are known for failure.

Comment: Can you please post photos of the situation inside the box in question?

Answer (score 1):

Black is carbon; carbon is relatively conductive compared to clean vinyl or other insulator. So anything black or brown indicates a leak path.  As a boy ,I miswired a 440 V box. The real electrician could not clean off the carbon well enough to use it and had to get some new equipment.

Comment: Big difference in 480v to 120v (even though the voltage to ground is only 277 on the 3 phase).  the thermoplastic insulation on Thhn is usually easy to clean I have done it many times as a real licensed electrician. With residential nmb / Romex it is usually easier to clean lower voltage lower flash temps.

Answer (score -3):

Only way to make sure it is ok , is to insulation test the wiring with a megger.Agree with the other statements of arking/sparking being bad.

Comment: First most DIY folks have only heard of a megger and in this case the test is useless. Megging a conductor that the end is black in open air will pass every time, you could strip all the black off and have no insulation and pass with a megger in this case this is the reason for my downvote. A visual inspection is all that is needed. We need to provide assistance that is something a diy could do. An example of this is someone stating that a time domain reflectometer is needed to repair cable faults when a new piece of cable is only a few dollars.

Comment: True , but if its arcing/sparking the current needs to travel somewhere? , whether its to neutral ,ground or another phase(unlikely).If cables are blackened we should find the cause of it , whether its caused by insulation failure(cut) or bridges in wiring or even incorrect sizing of the breaker that lead to over temp.

Comment: a loose connection is the most common cause for blackened wire in the US. Most commonly from backstabbed connections being used. I find excessive current with good connections in some cases melts the wire with out discoloration to a yellowing effect.